# Paint to Off-Screen Image

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I managed to draw GUI components on an image.  However, it only can be done by having a `JFrame` set to be visible.  The `JPanel.setVisible()` and `validate()` don't have any effect.  It would draw an empty image if the `JFrame` is commented out.

It is not neat when I want some function to do off-screen GUI painting, then pop a `JFrame` out or the server running such code don't have a screen or graphic card.

Please help, thanks very much.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JButton test = new JButton("Test Button center");
        JButton test2 = new JButton("Test Button2 south");
        JButton test3 = new JButton("Test Button3 at east");
        BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel(bl, false);
        jp.add(test2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        jp.add(test, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jp.add(test3, BorderLayout.EAST);

//      jp.validate();
//      jp.setVisible(true);
//      jp.show();
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.getContentPane().add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        //jp.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 400);
        BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(jf.getWidth(), jf.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        jp.paintAll(b.createGraphics());


        File output = new File("f:/screenie.png");

        try
        {
            ImageIO.write(b, "png", output);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. Is your question how to render a component to an Image on a system that doesn't have a screen or a graphics card?

Comment: It seems so. Or just printing the screen to an image, and sending that to the client.

Comment: it is the first :render a component to an Image on a system that doesn't have a screen or a graphics card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i managed drawing GUI components on image, however, it only can be done by having a Jframe set to be visible,

Components need to have a size before they can be painted. By default the size of a component is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. When you invoke pack() or setVisible(...) - which invokes pack() for you - the size of each component is then determined.

Check out [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) which can be used to create an image of any component and will set the size for you before creating the image.

Comment: then why  the " JPanel.setVisible(true); " won't do ?

Comment: All Swing components except for top level components (JFrame, JDialog) are already visible so invoking setVisible() on a panel doesn't do anything. Did you display the size of the panel after that statement? Did you display the visibility of the panel BEFORE invoking that statement?